# Enable hibernate filter in backing bean (SEAM)

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, seam

I am new to Hibernate and SEAM and struggling to enable a filter for a soft-delete on a fetched collection, I have set up the filter ok, however I cannot seem to invoke the enableFilter() call as per the documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/filters.html), I have tried the following code in the backing bean and also in the DAO that contains the query but both times I get a Null Pointer Exception, the example below shows what I tried to do in the backing bean...

```
import org.hibernate.Session;

@Stateful
@Name("competitionActions")
@Restrict("#{identity.isLoggedIn()}")
public class CompetitonActionsBean implements CompettionActions, Serializable {

    /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private Session session;

   @Override
   @Create
   @Begin(join=true)
   public void create(){
       session.enableFilter("deletedFilter");
       comps = competitionDAO.findCompetitionsForUser(user);
   }
```

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's a complete code sample, I'd say that `session` is null. You have `private Session session` defined, but it is never given a value. If you have it configured as a Seam-managed Hiberate session, you can do this:

```
@In
private Session session;
```

See http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/reference/en-US/html/persistence.html#d0e7410 for more details.